# Git Remote Add Privacy / History

Tags: git, github

When I write a command like

```
git remote add ...
```

Can the owner of the repository see that I added the repo? Furthermore, if I pull it, can the original owner of the repository see that I did this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git remote add` is a local command, and doesn't contact the remote repository. On the contrary, a `git pull` or `git fetch` does, and if the repo owner has the right monitoring tools in place/sufficient technical abilities, he can see that you're contacting it.

Comment: just curious, do you think most people have those monitoring tools for git pull in place? I'm pulling from a repo I don't think I should be pulling from (that is, I don't want the author to know) -- do you think this is an issue? Also, what tools would one use to monitor (sorry, this might be better as another question).

Comment: Don't know, it all depends if it's a sensitive repo... But for most of them they won't be monitored. I don't know anything about networks, so yes this would make another question

Comment: Do you mean that it's a repo that is unprotected, and that is shouldn't be normally accessible?

Comment: I mean it's unprotected, but I shouldn't be accessing it (for other reasons). Basically, I don't want the author to know I'm accessing the files at all.

Comment: If he wants to know he'll know, but he won't be notified.

Answer (score 2):

`git remote add` doesn't actually touch the URL you specify -- it only adds the relevant information to `.git/config`, unless you use the `-f` option to automatically `fetch` right away -- so no.

If you fetch or pull, then the owner of the repository *can* tell; it'll create log entries for ssh or http(s), depending on the protocol you're using.